# dashcode loading htm file problem

Tags: dashcode

is there anything like webview in dashcode. I am trying this for so long now. I get a htm link while parsing my xml file and i need to load this htm link in next subview in stacklayout template, i am not able to figure out which component i should use to load the link in the new view.Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same for a long time. To me it seems that it is not supported to link dashcode generated websites with other html content. The reason is for avoiding inhomogeneous styles.  Dashcode seems to be a tool to build a website from raw data that is stored in xml or json. For that it is a great tool.

The only way to get something like navigation between different views is using a stackLayout where you can have views as many as you want.

In iTunes University there are "Safari Development Essential Videos"...